# How to add an icon to Internal Storage Folder like Whatsapp or Snapchat (Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, download, android-internal-storage

My code for download files and save them in the internal storage is:

```
val downloadManager = context!!.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
val request = DownloadManager.Request(uri)
request.setTitle(filename)
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(FOLDER_NAME, File.separator + filename)
...
```

It works fine and files are saved in the correct folder, but I would like to add my app's icon to that folder like Whatsapp or Snapchat do:

[image: internal storage folders]

Does anyone know how to do it? Maybe adding anything to .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir() ?

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible. It's is recognized by your filemanager. File manager like solid explorer has a database in its assets where  there are entries for famous apps and their respective icons. Earlier I was also wondering. But  unfortunately it's not a default feature.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)